# How to Filter HTML Content in Template By URL Conditional

Tags: django

How do I create a template filter that only shows a section of code on a specified page? For example, my homepage which is my base_generic has code  that is specific to that page. Whenever another page is loaded that code should not be displayed.

I know I can use the block system but was wondering if I could also accomplish the task with a combination of the URL and If filter. See code below:

```py
 # Code for base_generic template

 {% url 'organizer-homepage' as home_page %}
     {% if home_page %}
     Shows Content Only on Specified Page     
     {% else %} Show Alternate on All Other Pages 
     {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
{% url 'organizer-homepage' as home_page %}
     {% if request.path == home_page %}
     Shows Content Only on Specified Page     
     {% else %} Show Alternate on All Other Pages 
     {% endif %}
```

Also make sure you have django.core.context_processors.request in your template context processors, which is there by default.